# Не адаптивный вид у формы

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Здравствуйте!

Проболему можно посмотреть [здесь](http://testbl777.tk/voprosi.php). Форма используется сторонняя, поэтому, менять ее (html код) очень не желательно.

Не могу понять, каким свойством можно сделать адаптивный внешний вид в мобильной версии?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите с помощью медиазапроса float: left; и padding-left: 120px;

http://joxi.ru/L21vNydF8V6pYA

http://joxi.ru/p27O0k3IoE0Ry2

Comment: спасибо большое! У меня прямо 2 вопроса! Что за средство разработки у вас на скрине? И как вы так быстро сообразили?

Про педдинг я понил и пробовал его уберать, а про флоат вообще забыл.

Comment: "Средство разработки" - это консоль в Хроме.
А соображение где может быть затык с опытом приходит наверное.
Бывает что и сам туплю над простым вопросом.

Comment: По f12 вызываете? Просто у меня по другому выглядит. Буду разбираться.

Comment: Там можно поменять цвет.

http://joxi.ru/l2Z1ZBQuwk8jKm

http://joxi.ru/eAOlbVNfxE4g4r